# How to cause memory fragmentation on a Linux based embedded device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, c, out-of-memory

**Hardware**

ARM

**What am I trying to do:**
Answer: I am trying to create memory fragmentation on a Linux 2.6.31 based swapless embedded device.

**Why:**
Answer:I am trying to port some patches to Linux 2.6.31 that will defragment the fragmented memory. In order to test if those patches are working correctly I'd like to try to fragment the memory first.

I learnt that continuous allocation and deallocation of memory by apps can lead to fragmentation. Therefore I wrote these simple C programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0, j = 0, randnum=0;
    while(1) {

        randnum = rand()%10000000;
        double *ptr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * randnum);

        for(j = 0 ; j < randnum; j++) {
            *(ptr+j) = (double)j+1;
        }

        free(ptr);
    }
}
```

==========

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0, j = 0, randnum=0;
    int arr[6] = { 3072, 7168, 15360 , 31744, 64512, 130048}; 
    while(1) {

        for (i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) {

            int *ptr = (int*) malloc(arr[i] * 93);  

            for(j = 0 ; j < arr[i] * 93 / sizeof(int); j++) {
                *(ptr+j) = j+1;
            }

            free(ptr);
        }
    }       
}
```

**How do I measure if memory is fragmented?:**
Answer:I look at the o/p of `/proc/buddyinfo`

**What do I need:?**
Can you suggest a better way to fragment the memory? Because those C programs work but very very slowly.

Comment: what is your hardware?

Comment: Maybe some sample [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html) can help.

Comment: @bersch Hardware is ARM.

Comment: Why do you think you need to defragment the memory? "An MMU also mitigates the problem of fragmentation of memory" and "ARM architecture-based application processors implement an MMU defined by ARM's virtual memory system architecture" Source  [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)

Comment: @bersch I want to fragment and not defragment the memory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But did you understand the principle of a memory manager?